# How to detect when a WebBrowserTask is closed?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser, windows-phone

Is there any event that occurs or variable that changes when a WebBrowserTask is closed? I want to do something when the user goes back to my app from a WebBrowserTask that is launched using:

```
        NavigationService.GoBack();
        WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
        wbt.Uri = new Uri("http://****.com");
        wbt.Show();
```

Comment: Your app will be de-activated when the browser is launched and re-activated when the browser closed.  So, you could detect the closing of the browser through the `PhoneApplicationService.Activated` event.  You could just persist some state about whether you've launched the browser and check that on activate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the OnNavigatedTo method like on this sample code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back && _usedWebBrowserTask)
    {
        //Do your stuff here

        _usedWebBrowserTask = false;
    }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

private void LaunchWebBrowserButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _usedWebBrowserTask = true;

    new WebBrowserTask()
    {
        Uri = new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com")
    }.Show();
}
```

Comment: Good point, then I suggest you go with monitoring the `PhoneApplicationService.Activated` event as it was suggested on the comments above!